# Объявить сессию в js функции

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, сессия

Задача стоит в том что бы при нажатии на крестик закрывания блока ,записать в сессию параметр, на основании которого потом при перезагрузке страницы знать отображать блок или нет , событие висит на крестике , так вот он работает на `jquery`+`js` ,собственно как объявить сессию `php` в функции `js` ? так как при написании `php` кода он выполняется независимо от того был нажат крести или нет.

Comment: Сделать запрос на сервер и там php запишет в сессию нужный флажок.

Comment: @AlexeyTen самый лучший способ за ddosить свой сервер :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ с чего бы? Сложно нажать на крестик больше одного раза.

Comment: @AlexeyTen согласен с вами в случае с крестиком и тем более в случае невставки секции пхп, но звучит кривовато все равно, тк если пользователь закрыл баннер то это надо в бд записывать, ну или он его еще раз увидит

Comment: Ну в моём комментарии главное это «отправить запрос на сервер», а где там хранятся данные это детали

Answer (score 0):

Это надо сделать в javascript секции кода

```
sessionStorage.setItem("key","value");
```

....

```
let value = sessionStorage.getItem("key");
```

Но [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)  это сессионное хранилище на клиенте, т.е. в браузере у пользователя, информация в нём протухнет вместе с сессией, для хранения состояния пользовательского интерфейса больше подходит [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)